# Passing string of parameters to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that needs to accept a parameter `@pnumber` as a string of values like `1001,1002,1003..`.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
create procedure dbo.getprojectdetails
    @pnumber nvarchar(255)
as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @SQL varchar(1000);
    set @SQL  = 'SELECT pnumber, name, isprocessed FROM dbo.sample WHERE pnumber IN ('+''''+'p'+ @pnumber +''''+')'

    exec(@SQL)
end
```

My data:

```
create table sample
(
     pnumber varchar(500), 
     name varchar(500), 
     isprocessed int
)

insert into sample
values ('p1001', 'project1', 1),
       ('p1002', 'project2', 0),
       ('p1003', 'project3', 0),
       ('p1004', 'project4', 1),
       ('p1005', 'project5', 0),
       ('p1006', 'project6', 1)

select * from sample
```

The problem with this stored procedure is - when I input the parameter as (1001,1002) the query produced looks like this:

```
SELECT pnumber, name, isprocessed 
FROM dbo.sample 
WHERE pnumber IN ('p1001,1002')
```

My query should actually look as below:

```
SELECT pnumber, name, isprocessed 
FROM dbo.sample 
WHERE pnumber IN ('p1001', 'p1002')
```

Rextester link : https://rextester.com/USZRB48933

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You should check out **table-valued parameters** (TVP) for your stored procedure to be able to safely and securely pass in a list/array/collection of values for parameters that will in fact work with the `IN` operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for the Dynamic SQL

If 2016+, you can use `string_split()`

**Example  [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6a9d13ad134cd0f5948943f61e4aa6e0)**

```
Declare @S varchar(max)='p1001,p1002'   -- assumed missing p was a typo

select * 
 From  sample
 Where pnumber in ( select * from string_split(@S,',') )
```

Returns

```
pnumber name        isprocessed
p1001   project1    1
p1002   project2    0
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @sq  char(1) = char(39); -- single quote

declare @pee char(1) = 'p';

set @pnumber = @sq + @pee + replace(@pnumber,',',@sq + ',' + @sq + @pee) + @sq;

declare @SQL varchar(1000);
    set @SQL  = 'SELECT pnumber, name, isprocessed FROM dbo.sample WHERE pnumber IN (' + 
                         @pnumber + ')'

-- print @SQL -- for debugging